# Contacts API editing Groups

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts

I am trying to edit a group title and Notes,

Editing title works for both *system groups* and *user created groups*,

Although notes column only persist if it is a *System group*(e.g. "Contacts", "Friends", "Family", "Coworkers"), 
I assume that it either doesn't save notes for *user created groups* or some how gets overwritten with *title column* content in *notes column*.

How can I use notes column in contact groups? is there any other way to store additional information with groups?
Here is my code snippet:

```
     ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops =new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

                ContentProviderOperation.Builder op = 
     ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withSelection(ContactsContract.Groups._ID + "="+group.getId(), null)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE, group.getTitle());

                HashMap<String, String> notes = group.getNotes();
                if(notes!=null && notes.size()>0){
                    op = op.withValue(ContactsContract.Groups.NOTES, new Gson().toJson(group.getNotes()));
                }

                ops.add(op.build());
                try {
                    getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this solution works for you, seems to be working for me.

I've used [ContentResolver.update()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#update(android.net.Uri,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) method.

> I assume that it either doesn't save notes for user created groups or some how gets overwritten with title column content in notes column.

I was able to update the notes for *user created groups* using below code.

> How can I use notes column in contact groups?

You can use notes column to save any **TEXT** value because it's defined of type **TEXT** in sqlite. See [ContactsContract.Groups.NOTES](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.GroupsColumns.html#NOTES) .

**(Tested on Google Pixel XL, Oreo 8.0.0)**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Cursor mCursor;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
    private ListView lvGroups;

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (mCursor != null)
            mCursor.close();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lvGroups = findViewById(R.id.lvGroups);
        checkAndRequestPermission();

    }

    private void checkAndRequestPermission() {
        if (PermissionChecker.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) == PermissionChecker.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            loadGroups();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS}, 123);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        boolean isGranted = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++) {
            if (grantResults[i] == PermissionChecker.PERMISSION_DENIED)
                isGranted = false;
        }
        if (isGranted)
            loadGroups();
        else
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS},123);
    }

    private void loadGroups() {
        mCursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI,null,ContactsContract.Groups.GROUP_IS_READ_ONLY + " = 0",null, ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE);

        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.contact_group_item, mCursor, new String[] {
                ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE,
                ContactsContract.Groups._ID,
                ContactsContract.Groups.ACCOUNT_NAME,
                ContactsContract.Groups.ACCOUNT_TYPE,
                ContactsContract.Groups.AUTO_ADD,
                ContactsContract.Groups.GROUP_IS_READ_ONLY,
                ContactsContract.Groups.GROUP_VISIBLE,
                ContactsContract.Groups.SOURCE_ID,
                ContactsContract.Groups.NOTES},
                new int[] {
                        R.id.text1,
                        R.id.text2,R.id.text3, R.id.text4, R.id.text5, R.id.text6, R.id.text7, R.id.text8, R.id.text9}, SimpleCursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);

        lvGroups.setAdapter(adapter);

        lvGroups.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Cursor cursor = adapter.getCursor();
                cursor.moveToPosition(position);

                int groupId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Groups._ID));
                ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                contentValues.put(ContactsContract.Groups.NOTES,"My test Notes");
                getContentResolver().update(ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI, contentValues, ContactsContract.Groups._ID + " = " + groupId, null);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks mate for the effort, but it is giving exactly same behavior, no matter what you use update() or applybatch(), Addition to that I noticed it is random, for some groups it keeps the value while for others it just reset, also it doesn't sync notes to other devices.

Answer (score 0):

The [`NOTES`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.GroupsColumns.html#NOTES) field is a String, it looks like you're trying to set a `JSON` object to it.

Check if this is working for you:

```
if (notes!=null && notes.size()>0) {
    op = op.withValue(ContactsContract.Groups.NOTES, "TEST STRING!");
}
```

If so, you'll need to extract the actual string you need from the `JSON` object, that would depend on the format of your `JSON`.

Comment: FYKI new Gson().toJson(group.getNotes()) returns a string.